# Node: How to throttle client request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, client

I would have used request + [throttle-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttled-request) but request is now deprecated.

So, in this scenario, how would you approach it:

Given a URL, how to throttle the download rate (bits per second)?

Comment: What framework are you using? Have you tried doing it yet? Can you provide us with the code on how you tried doing it?

Comment: @SamCurry No framework. Looking at lower level agent api now, to get the socket and use github.com/TooTallNate/node-throttle#throttle